# Maven Release Plugin - tagBase is ignored

Tags: maven, maven-release-plugin

I'm trying to create a release with the Maven Release Plugin, and it seems as if the `tagBase` setting is being completely ignored.

Here's what my pom looks like:

```
...
<scm>
    <developerConnection>scm:svn:http://svn.server/svn/repos/.../project/trunk</developerConnection>
</scm>
...
<build>
    ...
    <plugins>
        ...
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <tagBase>http://svn.server/svn/repos/.../project/branches</tagBase>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
...
```

And here's the mvn release command I'm running:

```
mvn release:prepare
```

I initially tried this with the `-DdryRun=true` option, and noticed that the **pom.xml.tag** file that got generated by the dry run was referencing the `.../project/tags/` directory instead of the `.../projects/branches/` directory specified in the `tagBase`.  I tried this without the dry run, and the results were the same.  The release was created in the **tags** directory in my SVN repository instead of in the **branches** directory per the `tagBase` setting in the pom.

Why is `tagBase` being ignored?  How can I get the maven release plugin to create the release under `.../project/branches/` instead of `.../project/tags/`?

#### Edit - Adding Some Additional Information:

I'm using version 2.5.3 of maven-release-plugin and Maven version 3.3.9.

After running the `mvn release:prepare -DdryRun=true` command, here's what the generated **release.properties** and **pom.xml.tag** files look like:

**release.properties**:

```
#release configuration
#Thu Aug 25 09:07:24 EDT 2016
scm.tagNameFormat=@{project.artifactId}-@{project.version}
scm.tag=project-1.0.0
project.scm.group.id\:project.tag=HEAD
pushChanges=true
scm.url=scm\:svn\:http\://svn.server/svn/repos/.../project/trunk
preparationGoals=clean verify
remoteTagging=true
projectVersionPolicyId=default
scm.commentPrefix=[maven-release-plugin] 
scm.tagBase=http\://svn.server/svn/repos/.../project/branches
project.scm.group.id\:project.developerConnection=scm\:svn\:http\://svn.server/svn/repos/.../project/trunk
project.dev.group.id\:project=1.0.1-SNAPSHOT
project.rel.group.id\:project=1.0.0
exec.snapshotReleasePluginAllowed=false
exec.additionalArguments=-P my-active-profile
completedPhase=end-release
```

**pom.xml.tag**:

```
...
<scm>
    <developerConnection>scm:svn:http://svn.server/svn/repos/.../project/tags/project-1.0.0</developerConnection>
</scm>
...
```

It looks like the `scm.tagBase` property is correct in the generated **release.properties** file, but the scm information in **pom.xml.tag** still references the **tags** directory instead of **branches**.

Comment: Did you clean the release before anything? It could be that you're reading old files. Run `mvn release:clean release:prepare -DdryRun=true`, this will make sure the `release.properties` and `pom.xml.tag` are recreated.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Yeah, I've tried quite a few things so far.  In between each of the `mvn release:prepare` commands I've tried, I've been running an `mvn release:clean`, but it still seems to be ignoring the `tagBase` setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I started digging through the `maven-release-plugin` code and the `maven-scm-provider-svn-commons` code, and I'm pretty sure I've figured out why this is happening.

If the `tagBase` property matches the standard naming convention for the `branches` directory in an SVN repository (for example, `http://svn.server/svn/repo/project/branches`), then the `tagBase` gets ignored in favor of the standard `tags` directory.  Here's the relevant code from version 1.9.4 of the `maven-scm-provider-svn-commons` project:

**SvnTagBranchUtils.java**:

```
public static String resolveUrl( String repositoryUrl, String tagBase, String subdir, ScmBranch branchTag )
{
    ...
    // User has a tagBase specified so just return the name appended to the tagBase
    if ( StringUtils.isNotEmpty( tagBase ) && !tagBase.equals( resolveTagBase( repositoryUrl ) )
        && !tagBase.equals( resolveBranchBase( repositoryUrl ) ) )
    {
        return appendPath( tagBase, branchTagName );
    }
    ...
    return addSuffix( appendPath( appendPath( projectRoot, subdir ), branchTagName ), queryString );
}
```

The `!tagBase.equals( resolveBranchBase( repositoryUrl) )` condition prevents the `tagBase` from being used if it matches the standard `/branches/` directory in the SVN repository layout.  I was even able to test this out using a different tagBases that didn't match the `/branches/` directory (for example, `http://svn.server/svn/repo/.../project/releases`) and it worked as expected.

Unfortunately, I'm still not 100% sure about the best way to have the releases written to `/branches/` when running `mvn release:prepare`.  I'm thinking I might just modify that bit of code in `maven-scm-provider-svn-commons` and figure out a way to get the `maven-release-plugin` to use my modified version of `svn-commons`.

Anyways, I hope this might help anyone who's trying to do something similar with the maven-release-plugin.